# Magento 2 :Header section modifications

Tags: magento2, blocks, header, logo

I'm trying to understand how the entire header section is put together, and wanted to move some things around just to try to understand how Magento is putting everything together.

How could I accomplish these changes without using any css as the main change maker? I'm looking for more of how to get these divs moved on the DOM structure then use css on top.

For example, the minicart moved up to the very top right; the logo moved to the center; the search box to the left; and main nav to the right.

I would like to completely `redefine/restructure` the entire `header/navigation` section. These don't have to make sense aesthetically, it is just for learning purposes.

Any feedback, resources, and/or help is much appreciated!

[image]

Comment: have you check this [link](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/xml-manage.html)  , It will help.